# Quebrar dados divididos por virgula

Tags: react, react-native

Estou tentando fazer um rastreador utilizando arduino, um módulo gps e um gsm.

Consigo receber a latitude, longitude e enviar para o celular como SMS, porém no celular estou tentando construir uma aplicação com `react-native`, no qual estou aprendendo, que mostre no mapa a localização.

Executando testes, consegui este código para monitorar as mensagens recebidas:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener';

export default class App extends Component {

  //constructor include last message
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lastMessage: 1 };
  }

  sms(){
    SmsListener.addListener(message => {
      this.setState({ lastMessage: message.body });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Scheduled jobs: {this.state.lastMessage} </Text>

        <Button 
          title="Buscar" 
          color="#115E54" 
          onPress={() => this.sms() } 
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

E este código para exibir o mapa:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { region } = this.props;
    console.log(region);

    return (
      <View style ={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}
        >
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Ambos funcionam dentro de suas funções.

O problema está no fato de que recebo os dados no SMS no formato `37.78825,-122.4324` e preciso quebrar este dado em dois para poder atribuir na `latitude` e `longitude`

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem você quer pegar os dados separados por virgula:

```
const str = "37.78825,-122.4324";
str = str.split(",");
console.log('latidude', res[0]) 
console.log('longitude', res[1]);
```

Teste aqui:
https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/ISHTNVJTFE

Comment: Bem isso que preciso, obrigado